# iOS 5 - In App purchases not getting products

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, in-app-purchase

I have configured some products and an in app purchases test account.

I am trying to get the products using the product identifier and the following request:

```
    SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObject: inappkey]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
```

The problem is that the array of products return empty. And the things is I don't know where to configure my AppId or InApp test account, so it doesn't know what application my products belong.

Where Can I do that?

Comment: I am guessing that inappkey is an array of strings that correspond to your product identifiers.  Are you getting anything in the invalidProductIdentifiers array in your productsRequest method?

Comment: @BP. yes i also facing same problem. and getting all my product in invalidProductIdentifiers array. i am using the the team member account to create in apppurchage product . is there may be team member a/c reason for getting the empty product list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the bundleID in the Info.plist file correct?

Comment: Yes, it began to work after 1 day, but without doing anything. Why?

Comment: Sometimes the in app purchase sandbox goes down